# how to realize serial writing is ended in windows

Tags: c++, serial-port, window

I everyone,
I'm trying to write on serial and also the serial should wait until all bytes are sent.
how can the serial wait to send all bytes?
I was surfing on the internet that I saw [this](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810467(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#serial-status).then, I tried to use the samples. unluckily, they didn't work well.
For example, I tried for use the following code:

```
BOOL WriteABuffer(char * lpBuf, DWORD dwToWrite)
{
   OVERLAPPED osWrite = {0};
   DWORD dwWritten;
   DWORD dwRes;
   BOOL fRes;

   // Create this write operation's OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent.
   osWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
   if (osWrite.hEvent == NULL)
      // error creating overlapped event handle
      return FALSE;

   // Issue write.
   if (!WriteFile(hComm, lpBuf, dwToWrite, &dwWritten, &osWrite)) {
      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) { 
         // WriteFile failed, but isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
         fRes = FALSE;
      }
      else
         // Write is pending.
         dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);
         switch(dwRes)
         {
            // OVERLAPPED structure's event has been signaled. 
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                 if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osWrite, &dwWritten, FALSE))
                       fRes = FALSE;
                 else
                  // Write operation completed successfully.
                  fRes = TRUE;
                 break;
            
            default:
                 // An error has occurred in WaitForSingleObject.
                 // This usually indicates a problem with the
                // OVERLAPPED structure's event handle.
                 fRes = FALSE;
                 break;
         }
      }
   }
   else
      // WriteFile completed immediately.
      fRes = TRUE;

   CloseHandle(osWrite.hEvent);
   return fRes;
}
```

But, it doesn't wait to send all bytes. after WriteFile(..)  I expect to wait. But, it'll reach to this line.

```
   else
      // WriteFile completed immediately.   
      fRes = TRUE;    <--------------------------- this line
```

And then it returns true.
why doesn't it  wait ?

==========Edit========

It's my current function for writing to serial but still it doesn't wait.

```
int RS232_SendBuf(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
  int n;
  DWORD dwCommEvent;
  DWORD dwStoredFlags;

  dwStoredFlags = EV_BREAK | EV_CTS | EV_DSR | EV_ERR | EV_RING | \
      EV_RLSD | EV_RXCHAR | EV_RXFLAG | EV_TXEMPTY;

  if (!SetCommMask(Cport[comport_number], dwStoredFlags)) {
      // Error setting communications mask
      return FALSE;
  }
  if(WriteFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL))
  {
    if (WaitCommEvent(Cport[comport_number], &dwCommEvent, NULL)) {
        // An error occurred waiting for the event.
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return(n);
    }
  }
  //while (!PurgeComm(Cport[comport_number], PURGE_TXABORT));
  return(-1);
}
```

Comment: Well, as the comment indicates, in this case `WriteFile` has completed synchronously, and returned after successfully sending all the bytes. There's nothing to wait for.

Comment: Did you pass `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when opening `hComm` handle?

Comment: Yes ,I did. but unfortunately It doesn't wait to send .